# O_RDWR undeclared for terminal

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.0.4LTS which is updated and upgraded.

I have written a code for serial communication.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <termios.h>
```

above files have been included in the code.

When i compile the code, it returns an error "O_RDWR undeclared" 
If i include fcntl.h, then compiler return error "incompatible type of argument 1", which means that the open function wants const char* type of argument.

```
struct termios TtyN;
open( TtyN, O_RDWR );
```

typecasting would not be appropriate. what is the correct solution?

Comment: Can you try adding #include <fcntl.h> and then try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open` takes a path string (`char *`), not a random `struct`. `struct termios` is for [specific terminal control APIs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios), not arbitrary file manipulation functions.

Perhaps you want to `open` something like `"/dev/tty#"` (where `#` is replaced with the `tty` number)?

Answer (score 3):

[`man 2 open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) will show the header files you need for `open()`. Namely,

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Next I suggest looking at [`man 3 termios`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios).

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of open is char*pathname, not a struct termios type.
Donot open it like that.